# Kinit with Spark when connecting to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, kerberos

I am trying to connect to Hive(hadoop cluster has kerberos authentication) from Spark which is Standalone.

Can someone let me know how to do kinit in spark program i could connect to hive?

UPDATE:My Spark is on different cluster from Hadoop

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a spark-shell open and you don't want to exit, and then re-kinit you could do something like this:

```
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder
import java.io.PrintWriter

//resets your kerberos login
val p1 = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("kdestroy")
p1.waitFor
//executes kinit, 
val p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("kinit")
val stdin = p.getOutputStream
val pw =new PrintWriter(stdin)
//val pwd = get_password() //get_password() is a function to get your password from a file, or wherever
pw.println(pwd) // you could put your password here , but plain text passwords are generally frowned upon
pw.close
p.waitFor
```

Comment: Since Hive uses the Hadoop auth library, you can also use a single line of Scala: `org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("the.donald@TRUMP.TOWER", "/some/path/to/the.donald.keytab")`

Comment: Is it same if the Spark is on Diff cluster?

Comment: The whole point of Kerberos is to authenticate a *remote* client -- so you need a Kerberos conf that points to the KDC used by Hadoop, a Hadoop conf that points to the cluster, and Hadoop client (JARs + native libs). Plus canonical DNS names for the cluster nodes. With all that, you can run Spark from anywhere. Including from Windows -- but that's more tricky because of the lack of "official" native libs.

Answer (score 0):

you should run the kinit command before init the spark-shell or submit a spark app (spark-submit). The other option is get the kerberos ticket using a keytab and run your spark program like this

```
bash -c "kinit -kt /path/to/key/mykey.keytab myuser@KERBEROS.SERVER.COM; spark-shell"
```

regards,

Comment: How do i do it if spark is on diff cluster.